# Broken Tobit regressions

Tags: r, linear-model, censoring, tobit-regression

I have a dataset with 43,422 observations and a left-censored (at 0) dependent variable.  Of the $n$ observations, 42,536 are left-censored and 886 are not.  I plan on analyzing this with a Tobit model and discovered there are three different implementations in R ([AER](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AER/index.html), [VGAM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html), and [censReg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censReg/index.html)).  Without thinking through a model, I decided to try regressing against a few of the other variables in the dataset to get a feel for presentation.  The model is nonsensical, but that should not be the point.  Much to my surprise, I get wildly different answers for the same model for the `AER` and `VGAM` implementations of Tobit, and `censReg` never returns.  So I tried again in Stata, which at least is returning reasonable responses (correctness is not verified).

My question is, what could cause the `AER`, `VGAM`, and `censReg` implementations to behave this way?  Is it possible my model is too censored?

Comment: This is probably a bad combination of identification issues (too many 0s) and numerics. Why don't you stick with Stata if it works?

Comment: I may have to.  That will really crimp my use of Sweave, though.

Comment: You can use Stata `file` to output anything in any format if you need to. But I agree, not having a fully functional analogue of Sweave for Stata is a sizable limitation.

Comment: An interesting idea, I post here to see if others find it valuable.  I realized ultimately, I only care if the result is non-0, so I switched to logit and probit.